# .net cms option with main page login function to pull from back end database

Tags: .net, asp.net, oracle, open-source, content-management-system

First off let me say I am not a developer (application or web) and may sound a little stupid how I word my post. So with that said...

I am trying to help bridge a gap between our web developer and it director over a question about a cms program/solution for one of our member sites. The basic needs are a .net type cms system that has a main page login prompt, which will allow the user name and password to be checked from the main member database (currently oracle if that matters) before allowing them to proceed to the internal web pages.

I only state .net because our other web sites are written in it and the it director is also the main programmer, and he uses it. He is also foreign and his english is pretty awful, which is why I am trying to help find some solutions.

Our web developer is a main php guy and from the discussion he can find no solution as far as cms goes that will allow the main page of the site to be the login/security stop for everything.

I have made all attempts to google and search these forums for solutions, but when you are not familiar with all the technology involved or terminology the questions sometimes aren't posed correctly.

Thanks everyone in advance for any suggestions and help!

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are looking for. I am confused about whether you are talking about your existing app?? or you want a new app? or may be its just me :)

Comment: We have a site currently for members with an asp login function on the landing page that allows all the members to authenticate with their credentials in our database for access to the site (various levels and access to the pages inside). The site is otherwise basic, and we are wanting to implement a cms that will allow us to more easily manage pages and content as it's added. But we are needing the same login functionality from the cms as on the current full site. I hope that made more sense!

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite your "login" code that you currently have to make a asp.net membership provider, this will make it compatible with pretty much every CMS out there.

As for the CMS choice, you can use DotNetNuke (DNN), it's one of the biggest CMS on asp.net right now. Either use the membership provider I mentioned above to implement the login or create a DNN module wrapper around your login code.

I also had good result with Umbraco CMS, it's a bit more lean than DNN but not as user friendly and definitely not as popular. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks kimphamg, I checked out both this morning and will try and get them at the office for evaluation with the web guy. I had one other part that I forgot to mention in my post. Their are 2 levels to the current "login" function. Some people see every internal page but one, and then the others will see them all. Do you know if we would we be able to use that same page restriction with either DNN or Umbraco? Thanks again for you help!

Comment: Yes, you can do that... if the role/group is set in the oracle database, you could create a role provider (similar to the membership provider but instead of authenticating user, the role provider check which group the user belong to).